# How to search string array's elements in Where Clause ?

Tags: c#, arrays, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have string array which included city names. I try to find user's city value where in CityList array.

```
string[] CityList = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",.... };
```

To  understand the problem more clearly, I wrote it . I know It won't be like that.

```
var user = db.User.Where(c=>c.City == CityList[0] || c=>c.City == CityList[1]....)
```

How could I solve that problem ? Does any one help me ? 
Thank you for your kind interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) (as you are trying to compare objects, use `Any` if you need a predicate):

```
db.User.Where(c=> CityList.Contains(c))
```